# How to pass data to Activities from a worker thread?

Tags: android

I'm working on a Qt/C++-project which is getting messages via a serial port. These messages are parsed and put into convenient classes which are all derived of a BaseMessage-class.
These are then passed via the signal/slot mechanisms of Qt to the various widgets and other threads that act on this data. The advantage is that I have convenient classes like GPSMessage with a getLongitude() function which are directly usable in the UI classes to update their data display.

I want to port this project to Android - so I'm looking for a way for classes to "register" themselves to the serial port handler and receive specific messages, more or less like the signal/slot behavior. I stumbled upon Intents, but I it seems like these are only used for very simple stuff like "Open that url: ..." and not to pass full blown objects.

How should I pass the message objects created by the serial port worker thread to the different activities?

Comment: Checkout Handler class. You'll be able to pass data using it (with Parcelable objects).